# How to Insert JSON data object to Spring MVC application (via controller) with Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc

I want to Insert JSON data object (User) to my Spring MVC application (via controller) with Jquery. if code is like follow how can I accomplish this? Thanks.

### User Object

```
public class User {
    private Integer usId;
    private String usName;
    private Boolean usActive;
}
```

### Spring Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    private Validator validator;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, ? extends Object> create(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletResponse response) {


        Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> failures = validator.validate(user);
        userService.insert(user);

        if (!failures.isEmpty()) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            return validationMessages(failures);
        } else {

            return Collections.singletonMap("id", user.getUsId());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("/user", { usName: "John", usActive: "true" } );
```

Comment: Hi DmityB! Many thanks for your feedback, but this was not working  for me know :(. Actually my Spring application works as "Skeleton" and I want to post this user object from "Stub", according to your sugetion I have try as follow also, but it was also now working for me :(. Thanks

$.postJSON("http://192.168.3.111:8080/skeleton-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/user", { usName: "John", usActive: "true" } );

Comment: Are you hitting a cross domain post restriction? This is a security constraint that prevents browser from posting from one domain to another via Ajax.

Comment: Hi DmityB! Thanks for your feedback. Yes when I execute that ($.postJSON("user";, { usName: "John", usActive: "true" } ); ) within locally (same application of Skeleton) it works finely. Then can you please tell me how I can accomplish this via remote request (as $.postJSON("192.168.3.111:8080/skeleton-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/user";, { usName: "John", usActive: "true" } ); kike from "Stub")

Comment: You can not, look-up JSONP for a way to do cross-domain GET. Another way to do is regular form post. Yet another is a local "proxy" servlet that will redirect your request server side.